# How to apply a Gaussian Blur while rendering a CATiledLayer?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-image, gaussianblur

I'm using `CATiledLayer` to render some 2D graphics in the `draw(in:)` callback.

The scene is composed of elements such as open & filled paths, images, etc that are drawn procedurally using the painter's model. Some areas need to be blurred, and then there may be non-blurred graphics drawn on top of them.

I believe that Gaussian blurs need a `CIImage` to apply to, but don't know what the best way is to create a `CIImage` in this scenario. I've spent a fair bit of time searching for a solution, but haven't come up with anything. I would like to avoid having to compose the scene using one or more offscreen bitmaps, and having to blit the result back to the CALayer.

Comment: I might - emphasis on might :-) - be able to help but do you have some code to help me? Also, what do you mean by *"apply Gaussian blurs to certain regions"*?

Comment: By certain regions, I mean not the entire draw rect, but smaller areas, which you can assume are defined by UIBezierPaths. 

Not sure what code you need, there's not a lot of setup in my scenario. As a concrete case, how do you apply a Gaussian blur to a single area whose path is given, while rendering to a CATiledLayer (or any CALayer for that matter)?

Comment: Simply put, you can't. While the Apple doc (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410901-filters) is likely old, testing things today shows it to still be valid. See the *Special Considerations* at the bottom of the link.

Comment: If I understand, you wish to "break up" an image into "sub images" and apply a blur to it. As long as these "pieces" are rectangular, you can do at least two things (also, see if there's some `CoreGraphics` magic). (1) If you know GLSL coding, write your own `CIKernel` and/or use GPUImage2 and send as input the X/Y coordinates to blur. (2) Probably the easiest option would be to chain `CICrop` and `CIGaussianBlur` to break things up and then "stitch" the output together. (And yes, if you want something *not* rectangular....

Comment: @dfd, I've updated the question. 1) The areas are not rectangular. 2) There may be non-blurred content on top of the blur area, so setting a filter on the CALayer wouldn't work even if iOS supported it.

Comment: FIrst, sorry to say this, but I believe *any* `CALAyer` or subclass doesn't work in iOS. (Can you give me a concrete example that does? Maybe I can help.) Second, I *do* have things where something like a `UITableView` or a `UISlider` is "above" a `UIVisualEffectView` that work well. It may not be what you want, but it brings to mind.... Third, maybe if you work with a `UIVisualEffectView (or even a container view that is simply a custom `UIView`) that is `clippedToBounds` of sorts, you might achieve what you want....

Comment: To the point: Can you get a simple `UIView` to be the shape of your `UIBezierPath`? If so, forget about using the layer. Put a `GLKView` (my choice) or a `UIImageView` to cover the **entire** view and...  I don't know... roll your own "shaped" `UIVisualEffectView`? That's the best help I can be. Good luck!